# Xamarin.Forms binding using SetBinding not working

Tags: c#, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have base custom control:

```
public class TabItem : ContentView
{
    public TabItem()
    {
        SetBinding(HeaderProperty, new Binding("Header"));
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Header", typeof(string), typeof(TabItem), default(string));

    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TabItem.HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TabItem.HeaderProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I derive from this class and set Binding context:

```
public partial class FeedbackView : TabItem
{
   public FeedbackView(FeedbackViewModel viewModel)
   {
       InitializeComponent();    
       Content.BindingContext = viewModel;    
   }
}
```

This is view model:

```
 public class FeedbackViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     private string header;

     public FeedbackViewModel()
     {
         Header = "Test Header";
     }

     public string Header
     {
         get { return header; }
         set
         {
             header = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Header");
         }
      }
```

When I run it - header not binds to viewmodel's property.
Is there something obvious that I forgot? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It seems that your forgot to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `FeedbackViewModel`.

Comment: @Wosi Sorry, I forgot that my `FeedbackViewModel` derived from `BaseViewModel` class where `INotifyPropertyChanged` Already implemented. I edit code in question.

Answer (score 1):

As you do not share the `XAML` part of `FeedbackView`, one can only guess, but let's try nonetheless:

you say:

> header not binds to viewmodel's property

I'm quite sure (from the code you've shared) the `Header` property of `TabItem` is set, even if your way of doing binding is unconventional. Is this the issue ? or your issue is that you don't have anything displayed on screen ?

Solving the "nothing displayed" issue require some changes to your code. First, set the `propertyChanged` arg on `BindableProperty.Create`

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty HeaderProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create("Header", typeof(string), typeof(TabItem), default(string),
    propertyChanged: OnHeaderChanged);
```

implements it, and create a virtual method so you can override it in your subviews

```cs
static void OnHeaderChanged (BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newvalue)
{
    ((TabItem)bindable).OnHeaderChanged ((string)oldValue, (string)newValue);
}

protected virtual void OnHeaderChanged (string oldValue, string newValue)
{
}
```

Now, in your derived `FeedbackView`, you can override `OnHeaderChanged` and set the label according to the `Header`

```cs
protected override void OnHeaderChanged (string oldValue, string newValue)
{
    //headerLabel is defined in Xaml, and has a x:Name="headerLabel"
    headerLabel.Text = newValue;
}
```

This should get you started.

As a last note, I'd say that setting the Binding in the `TabItem` ctor is, well, unconventional. It breaks the MVVM pattern as the View (TabItem) makes some assumption about the structure of the ViewModel (and the existence of an Header property).

That binding is normally set on the TabItem inherited instance.

```cs
var feedback = new FeedbackView (myVm);
feedback.SetBinding (TabItem.HeaderProperty, "Header");
```

or, as passing the VM as ctor parameter already *breaks* MVVM, you could eventually do that in `FeedbackView` ctor.

This last part is my humble opinion. Don't start a heated discussion about it, or do it without me involved :)

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `BindableProperty` is wrong. Look here how to do it right: https://blog.xamarin.com/using-custom-controls-in-xamarin.forms-on-android/

The `Binding` to the property is usually done inside `Page`. There you bind the property of your `ViewModel` to the control's `BindableProperty`. You don't do it inside the control itself.

Comment: Why I can't define binding inside control itself? I also update code in question. Is it correct now?

Comment: The control doesn't know anything about the `ViewModel`. The name of the bound property is not important to the `BindableProperty`. Otherwise `TextView.TextProperty` could only be bound to a property named `text` instead of binding it to `CustomerViewModel.LastName` or `UserViewModel.EmailAddress`. The binding is done in the `Page` or its `XAML` file. This is the connection between `ViewModel` and `Control`. So your implementation is still wrong. Read the blog entry and you'll see the difference.